# Percentage Difference between 3rd quartile and the first quartile

Tags: statistics

There was one question in my GRE Prep that goes like this:

"Find the percentage difference between the first and the third quartile"

The formula that was given was (Q3-Q1)/ (Average of Q3 & Q1).

If this is true, can anyone explain why this is? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment.** The purpose seems to be to test whether you can find $Q_1$ and
$Q_3.$ There many slightly different ways to find quartiles, depending
on on how ties and various sample sizes are handled. I hope
finding the quartiles is straightforward in this problem. (Are data given for
this question? What possible answers are given?)

I'm not sure what practical use there would be for 'the percentage difference'
between quartiles.  I don't think this is the kind of question a
practicing statistician would every ask. But then GRE questions are not exactly noted for their practical
use.

However, if you are going
to do answer the question, using the average in the denominator seems reasonable,
because it is not clear which *one* of the quartiles would be used
as the denominator. (As in the question, "What percentage increase
is $Q_3$ over $Q_1?")$

*Note:* For a symmetrical distribution (or sample) the average of $Q_1$ and $Q_3$
will be the median (occasionally denoted $Q_2.)$

Answer (score 0):

This is the usual formula for the percentage difference of any two numbers.  It doesn't matter that they are quartiles.  Sometimes the denominator is one of the numbers if that is regarded as the starting value, but here you don't have that so you use the average.  What is the percentage difference between $8$ and $10$?  It is $\frac {10-8}{\frac {10+8}2}$